# How to include multiple commands in a JDBC SQL query to Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, ora-00911

I'm completely new to Oracle (I come from MySQL and MSSQL) and am novice at JDBC. One of my table creation queries looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  "LISTS" 
   ("ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOMAIN_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "LISTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_LISTS" 
  before insert on "LISTS"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "LISTS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.ID from dual; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_LISTS" ENABLE
/
```

When I try to `connection.createStatement().execute()` this query, I get `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`. If I remove the slashes, I get the same. If I try replacing them with semicolons, I get `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character`.

Is it not possible to include multiple commands in one query in JDBC and/or Oracle? Or am I just missing some kind of syntax to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those are separate statements.  Issue one at a time via separate Statement objects via `Connection#createStatement()` or via multiple SQL calls to `Statement#execute(String)`.

Conversely, what is your reason for wanting them in one delineated statement?

Comment: It's not so important that they are one statement (I'd separated them out into three strings as a workaround before posting), I just wanted to see if I was missing something and/or doing it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You can trick JDBC with some Oracles-specific syntax, but JDBC's object model really is designed to pass statement-level commands over to the DB as each would potentially have responses/exceptions.

Comment: Makes sense =) Mostly I was confused that the sql file that Oracle/Apex itself spit out came back as invalid syntax when I tried to run it back through Apex or through JDBC.

Answer (score 3):

For oracle if you include your sql between BEGIN and END; it should work.

Ex:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE  "LISTS" 
       ("ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DOMAIN_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        CONSTRAINT "LISTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
       )
    ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_LISTS" 
      before insert on "LISTS"               
      for each row  
    begin   
        select "LISTS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.ID from dual; 
    end; 
    ;

    ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_LISTS" ENABLE;
END;
```

Comment: I think this is only applicable for UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements- I couldn't get it to work when my SQL had CREATE/DROP statements

Comment: The following worked for me:  
  `String wa = """DECLARE
    v_command VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN
    v_command :='CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED $clsName AS $clsDef';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_command;
    END;"""  
  jdbcTemplate.execute(wa)`

Comment: Also note create statements are DDL whereas Update(etc) statements are DML. I wouldn't recommend aggregating DML in PLSQL but rather doing batch execution.